# Updating a Dictionary by Key fails even when key found

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collections, dictionary

This makes no sense

I have a series of dictionaries of Data from which I am trying to create another.

So, I am looping through stuff and checking for keys, updating the key where applicable, but have run into the strangest problem

```
If completeDictionary.ContainsKey(sale("splitType1")) Then
    completeDictionary(sale("splitType1")) += (sale("splitPay1") - pxValues)
Else
    completeDictionary.Add(sale("splitType1"), (sale("splitPay1") - pxValues))
End If
```

Here we are checking if a key in `completeDictionary` exists, with the name of `sale("splitType1")` then if the key exists, updating it's value, and if not, adding it with a new value.

This should work fine, but it seems to be finding the key but is unable to update it, I get this error:

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

and this refers to the line:

```
completeDictionary(sale("splitType1")) += (sale("splitPay1") - pxValues)
```

But it shouldn't be running that line if the key doens't exists, hence the `If` before it!!

`completeDictionary` is created by looping through an array:

```
Dim completeDictionary As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Double)
For Each Type as string In paymentTypes << paymentTypes is simply an array
    completeDictionary.Add(Type, 0.0)
Next
```

Any help with this frustrating problem much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking for `splitType1`, but also accessing `splitPay1` - that's probably the missing entry:

```
completeDictionary(sale("splitType1")) += (sale("splitPay1") - pxValues)
```

Comment: I don't think `sale("splitPay1")` is a key in the dictionary

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but it isn't that. sale("splitPay1") and sale("splitType1") come from a database table. They can't not be there. Sorry, I will update the question as that part isnt clear.

Comment: @JamieHartnoll - Did you debug trough? Did you check?

Comment: ARRGRHHHH Complete Idiot!! Sorry.... you're right, I changed the bloody table row names!!!

Comment: Can't believe I wasted so much time on that... I'll get my coat!